# SharePoint People Picker / SP Group containing AD Group

Tags: active-directory, groups, people-picker, clientpeoplepicker

Problem:
I have an AD group that is used to maintain a list of approvers at the manager level within my organization. We now need to use this exact same list across multiple sites. Our solution was to create an active directory group, and add it to a group on each site to filter a people picker. However, once this is done, the people picker can't find the members who are in the AD Group, but it can see the users manually added to the SharePoint group.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer you question:
http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/05/20/active-directory-groups-vs-sharepoint-groups-for-user-management-a-dilemma-aspx/

There are some differences in using ad groups vs sharepoint groups. One of the differences is that you can't view the members of an ad group in SharePoint. So a people picker with the limitation on only users within a SharePoint group, does not populate the users from an AD group.